# Battery, wifi, Bluetooth, Ethernet and USB ports not being detected

Tags: usb, bluetooth, ethernet, ubuntu-drivers, wifi-hardware-switch

A few days back some updates were available and I installed them. However, after the update the battery is not being detected. The Bluetooth is not working. The USB ports do not detect any USB device. The Ethernet port is not connecting. WiFi is also not working. However, all of these are working in Windows which proves it is not a hardware issue. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I initially thought it to be an issue with the desktop environment. So I tried all the 4 DEs available on my system - GNOME, KDE, Unity and Cinnamon. However, the issues were in all the 4 DEs. Please take note that I cant now connect to Internet in any way. So an offline solution is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reinstall has fixed the problem.